# Movement average in SQL

Tags: sql

i have table like this:

```
Date  |Shop Code |Good code |Value
01.11    1001        1        1000.00
01.11    1001        2        799.00
01.11    1002        1        899.00
03.12    1003        2        500.00
03.12    1003        3        760.00
```

and i need to have

1. table with SUM for each shop code for each good code for each date
2. And then i need to have 10 day movement average on the column of sum(value) per each shop (5 days before and 5 days after)

Comment: Use a window function: `sum(value) over (partition by shop_code order by date range between interval '5 days' preceding and interval '5 days' following` - but it depends on the DBMS product you are using if that works or not.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i need Movement Average for each shop_code, for each date on sum(value) on good code

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the expected output based on your sample data.

Comment: Can you please edit the question with your query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can express what you want in standard SQL as:

```
select shop_code, good_code, date, sum(value),
       avg(sum(value)) over (partition by shop_code, good_code 
                             order by date
                             range between interval '9 day' preceding and current row
                            ) as avg10
from t
group by shop_code, good_code, date;
```

Although this is standard functionality, not all databases support it or have variations on the syntax.

Comment: It takes 5 days before and 5 days after? or 10 days before?

Comment: @Xum3abodMedia . . . It takes 9 days before and the current date.  Of course, you can adjust the interval to be whatever you want.